# Pandas series inserted into dataframe are read as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm finding that when adding a series, based on the same time-period, to an existing dataframe it gets imported as NaNs. The dataframe has a field column, but I don't understand why that should change anything. To see the steps of my code, you can review the attached image. Hope that someone can help!

[Illustration showing how the dataframe that the series is inserted into and how it gets read as NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OALaL.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). This means no links or images, just text.

Comment: the indexes are not the same. What about actual? please provide information as code not as images

Comment: Thank you for the link jpp! It's difficult for me to reproduce as the data is quite complex. @Quickbeam2k1: You're right that one data frame is a multi-index and the other just a series. However, the field 'Actual' is not relevant at all. Any way to overwrite it so that I can add the series

Comment: @johan, we all have the problem, just try to create some dummy data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value in the Field Index column is "actual" for every row, a solution could be the following:

```
test.reset_index().set_index('Date').assign(m1=m1)
```

That solution works but it can be done shorter:

```
days = pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field': ['Actual']*3, 'Date': days, 'Val':[1, 2, 3]}).set_index(['Field', 'Date'])
m1 = pd.Series([0, 2, 4], index=days)

df.reset_index(level='Field').assign(m1=m1)
    Field   Val m1
Date            
2018-01-31  Actual  1   0
2018-02-28  Actual  2   2
2018-03-31  Actual  3   4
```

btw, that would be a nice mcve